# pass html tags in textarea

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am using a texteditor TinyMCE for allowing users to enter some long descriptions on my site.  The problem is when I try to submit the form, it gives error:

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client.

I understand this is because the texteditor includes paragraph tags and other html tags inside the textarea. How i do solve this problem and store the textarea data in my database?

This is my aspx file code(It has other asp.net controls which i omitted from this code).
I am using C# code behind to insert data into database.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>
       tinymce.init({ selector: 'textarea' });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="story" cols="50" rows="15"> 
    </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer. I set the ValidateRequest="false" and then when i capture the Request.Form value, I just use Server.HtmlEncode to escape the HTML tags. While retrieving the data, I use Server.HtmlDecode to decode and display the html tags and maintain formatting.

Comment: Just make sure you always remove / don't accept anything containing `<script>` tags as that can easily lead to XSS.